# Android project structure in Android view

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to have multiple subfolders/folders for layout, drawable etc. that appear in Android view, not only Project view?

I know that you can create more layout folders or even res folders, but once I change to Android View, they all appear in the same place.

And as an overall good practice, what is a good way to organise a project? Should I use modules, keep everything in the same place, divide into folders/subfolders...?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible with android studio.